# Open GL screen dimenstions or -1 to 1

Tags: c++, opengl

I was wondering if you have to do anything to be able to use the screen dimensions instead of the -1 to 1 scale in open GL.

So instead of drawing shapes using using 0.75 or 0.5 etc.
Could I use anything between 0 and 500 if my screen width and height are both 500?

Comment: `glOrtho`, `gluPerspective`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Vertex shader output must be on this [-1,1] scale. This is a resolution independent technique, which is preferable.

However, fragment shader input can use both scales. Use the built-in variable gl_FragCoord to read the fragment coordinates.

Comment: Actually, `gl_Position` is in clip space, where the viewing volume is [-w,w]. The [-1,1] range are normalized device coords.